# Duplicate Symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_myClass

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am newbie into MAC objective Programming. I developed a simple class with few functions.

The files are something like follows.

myClass.h, myClass.m and main.m.

I am getting the linker error : Duplicate Symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_S_myClass. I tried all possibilities like removing/adding header and .m files. But is not going.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

krissam

Comment: Can you show the contents of the files (or at least a rough outline including imports and declarations)?

Answer (score 0):

I understood the issue.

The mistake I did was to select an invalid project type while creating the project.

When we need to develop objective-C application, the Project Type should be "Foundation". Instead I selected C++  StdC++ because of which I was getting the linker issue.

I could resolve the issue.

Thanks for views and response.